# How to uninstall python jupyter correctly?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I have `jupyter` installed with `python3.5` on my *Mac OSX*, but I want the `python2.7` version.  So, I basically need to uninstall the `3.5` version, and reinstall the `2.7` version.

But for some reason I can't uninstall the 3.5 version.  I tried `sudo python3 -m pip uninstall jupyter`, and you can see the results below:

```
✔  ~/current/directory  
20:08 $ which jupyter
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/jupyter
✔  ~/current/directory  
20:08 $ sudo python3 -m pip uninstall jupyter
The directory '/Users/<username>/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Cannot uninstall requirement jupyter, not installed
The directory '/Users/<username>/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
✘-1  ~/current/directory  
20:09 $ which jupyter
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/jupyter
```

...as you can see above, the `which jupyter` command still returns a valid path, AND not only that.  I'm still able to launch `jupyter notebook` from the command line, and it opens a notebook.

How do I correctly get rid of my existing version of `jupyter` ? OR, if someone knows how to ADD a `python2` kernel to my existing `jupyter`, that would be fine too.  Is that possible?

All I can think of is to manually kill the files and subfolders inside of `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/`, but this seems unnecessarily brutal?

Comment: Try `sudo -H python3 -m pip uninstall jupyter`.

Comment: The result is: `20:39 $ sudo -H python3 -m pip uninstall jupyter
Password:
Cannot uninstall requirement jupyter, not installed
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
`

Comment: @edwinksl, it doesn't solve the issue it seems like.  But thank you.

Comment: any other suggestions?

Comment: Maybe try without `sudo`?

Comment: Same issue, just says `Cannot uninstall requirement jupyter, not installed`

Comment: Pretty odd I would say. Let's hope someone who knows more will come along...

Comment: If you want to use Python 2 in notebooks, you can set that up without having to uninstall Jupyter: http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-python-2-and-3

Answer (score 3):

From your `home` folder, delete `~/AnacondaProjects`. After that remove the `export` of `Anaconda environment variable` from your bash profile `~/.bashrc` .

Answer (score 3):

The answer over here solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42277762/8057434

I'll just summarize what to do.
Run

`conda uninstall notebook nbconvert nbformat ipykernel ipywidgets qtconsole traitlets tornado jupyter_* ipython_genutils jinja2 -y`

in your terminal.

You can use `pip uninstall` instead of `conda uninstall` if you aren't using anaconda.

Comment: I also found using `pip freeze | grep jupyter` and `pip3 freeze | grep jupyter` helpful to find package names to uninstall.

Answer (score 1):

Use pip3 instead of pip

```
pip3 uninstall jupyter
```

You can install for both python 2 and python 3 on the same computer as long as you use the correct pip version

Answer (score 0):

> I have jupyter installed with python3.5 on my Mac OSX, but I want the python2.7 version.

Anaconda is a great way to install python software that you need for specific projects.

1. Download from https://www.continuum.io/downloads#macos
2. as said, `bash Anaconda2-4.3.1-MacOSX-x86_64.sh` (the 2.7 version in your case)
3. go to the installed directory and type `source bin/activate`

This creates a command-line environment which has just the right level of libraries etc. Inside, you can install further data with f.ex. `conda install numpy`. To fix a version, use `conda install numpy=1.10`.

Answer (score 0):

You should uninstall the jupyter-core, jupyter-console, jupyter-client seperately. After remove them all, these is no package found named jupyter.