# How to uninstall Jupyter notebook that was installed with pip3

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I've installed anaconda and that came with its own Jupyter version so I want to uninstall the Jupyter that I installed using pip3.  I searched for instruction and tried using `pip3 uninstall Jupyter`, but that does not seem correct because I get the following, which it says is Jupyter 1.0.0:

```
Uninstalling jupyter-1.0.0:
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/__pycache__/jupyter.cpython-36.pyc
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter-1.0.0.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter-1.0.0.dist-info/INSTALLER
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter-1.0.0.dist-info/METADATA
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter-1.0.0.dist-info/RECORD
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter-1.0.0.dist-info/WHEEL
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter-1.0.0.dist-info/metadata.json
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter-1.0.0.dist-info/pbr.json
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter-1.0.0.dist-info/top_level.txt
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter.py
```

I know I can also try `pip3 uninstall notebook`, but that shows a bunch of files that I'm not sure is actually Jupyter.

This must seem like such a simple question, but I've searched and haven't found clear answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there's no simple solution. The "pip install jupyter" command installs various dependencies and so you'll probably have to uninstall  them all seperately.

The packages associated with Jupyter are:

- notebook
- nbconvert
- nbformat
- ipykernel
- ipywidgets
- qtconsole
- traitlets
- tornado
- anything with jupyter in front of it (jupyter_core, jupyter_client etc.)
- ipython_genutils
- jinja2

Some of these aren't Jupyter only (tornado, qtconsole, jinja2 etc) but if you're sure you're not using them then feel free to uninstall.

Comment: I also found using `pip freeze | grep jupyter` and `pip3 freeze | grep jupyter` helpful to find package names to uninstall.