# How to uninstall Jupyter note book installed by pip3

Tags: macos, pip, jupyter-notebook, uninstallation

I installed Jupyter notebook using pip3 on OSX. Later, I realised, I should do it through anaconda because it has loads of libraries which I need for my on-line study. So I was about trying to uninstall jupyter, then install anaconda. I see many questions when people messed up uninstall jupyter notebook. So I want to do it correct way.

I wanted to do this way

```
$ pip install pip-autoremove
$ pip-autoremove jupyter -y
```

or may be using pip3 instead, anyway, does anyone know if it is the right way to do? 
I got this from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052232/how-to-uninstall-jupyter)

Thanks x

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have just tried

```
$ pip3 install pip-autoremove
$ pip-autoremove jupyter -y
```

It cleared all. I checked with

```
pip3 freeze | grep jupyter
which jupyter
```

Nothing came back. So it's all good.

There is also other suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629879/how-to-uninstall-python-jupyter-correctly)

Below is copy from the link:(you might need to use pip3)
Run conda uninstall notebook nbconvert nbformat ipykernel ipywidgets qtconsole traitlets tornado jupyter_* ipython_genutils jinja2 -y in your terminal. You can use pip uninstall instead of conda uninstall if you aren't using anaconda.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove it like this:

```
pip3 uninstall notebook
```

You should use conda uninstall if you installed it with conda.

Answer (score 1):

to make sure no packages are leftover, you can run `pip freeze | grep jupyter` and `pip3 freeze | grep jupyter` .
if you get any packages - just remove then with `pip uninstall <package-name>`