# GDB Error gdb: error while loading shared libraries: libffi.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: gdb, manjaro

I'm am trying to get to use GDB, so I run Sudo pacman -S gdb. I run it then try the following command, gdb help. And get this error. *"gdb: error while loading shared libraries: libffi.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
"* I am on Manjaro. How can I get around this? Did I install gdb wrong?

EDIT: Heres some more information, later I ran the command, touch p.py, and then ran, code . to open vscode and got this! "electron6: error while loading shared libraries: libffi.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python interpreter is looking for a version of libffi that does not exist on your system. Rebuild the python interpreter and it will look for a version that exists on your system.

```
yay --rebuild -S python38
```

Replace python38 with the interpreter used by the program you are calling.

Related:

https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/python38/

[Ubuntu 20.04 upgrade, Python missing libffi.so.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61875869/ubuntu-20-04-upgrade-python-missing-libffi-so-6/61876234#61876234)