# AVISPA on Ubuntu 20.04 error with libffi.so.6 : no such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-20.04

AVISPA worked properly on Ubuntu 18.04. After upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04, AVISPA gives the error "error while loading shared libraries: libffi.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". A quick search explains that Ubuntu 20.04 upgraded libffi.so.6 to lib.so.7 which leads to this error. How can I make AVISPA access libffi.so.7? Or Is there a way to install libffi.so.6 into my system and make AVISPA run normally as before the Ubuntu upgrade?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 upgrade, Python missing libffi.so.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61875869/ubuntu-20-04-upgrade-python-missing-libffi-so-6)

Answer (score 0):

AVISPA is no longer maintained but you can use the virtualBox image here:

http://people.irisa.fr/Thomas.Genet/span/#VDI

Best