# LoadError on github ci workflow running with rails and ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github-actions, github-ci

I recently upgraded my GitHub CI workflow to use `ubuntu-22.04` from previously used `ubuntu-18.04` since `ubuntu-18.04` would be deprecated this year in December. As soon as I upgraded it, it started failing the `setup database` on GitHub CI. This is the following error I got on GitHub CI -

`LoadError: libffi.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/runner/work/documentor/documentor/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.so`

I am using `ruby 2.7.5` and `rails 6.1.3`. I already have the gem `ffi` installed and inside my Gemfile. How can I resolve it?

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61875869/ubuntu-20-04-upgrade-python-missing-libffi-so-6 ?

Comment: Yes I did. Locally everything is fine. It is the workflow on GitHub CI that is failing.