R fails to build shared library tiff.so
Using install.packages("tiff"), the compiling completes, but it fails in the final testing step.
This is done on Ubuntu 20.04. R version is 4.1.0. I've been successful to this point in building several other packages with install.packages().
> install.packages("tiff")
Installing package into ‘/home/steve/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/tiff_0.1-12.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 68272 bytes (66 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 66 KB

* installing *source* package ‘tiff’ ...
** package ‘tiff’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
[...check for all header files and configuration have "yes" answers]
checking for TIFFClientOpen in -ltiff... yes
configure:  PKG_CPPFLAGS:  
configure:  PKG_LIBS    : -ltiff  
checking for tiff.h... yes
checking for tiffio.h... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-tbZjLv/r-base-4.1.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c common.c -o common.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-tbZjLv/r-base-4.1.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c read.c -o read.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-tbZjLv/r-base-4.1.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c reg.c -o reg.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-tbZjLv/r-base-4.1.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c write.c -o write.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o tiff.so common.o read.o reg.o write.o -ltiff -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/steve/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/00LOCK-tiff/00new/tiff/libs
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tiff’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/steve/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/00LOCK-tiff/00new/tiff/libs/tiff.so':
  libtiff.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/steve/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/tiff’



This doesn't answer your question exactly but it's owing to issues like this that I've started to use r2u on ubuntu: https://github.com/eddelbuettel/r2u?tab=readme-ov-file - makes everything much easier. Also R 4.1 is getting quite old now - at a certain point that may start to cause issues e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61875869/ubuntu-20-04-upgrade-python-missing-libffi-so-6
